# .chm not working on specific machine

Tags: c#, .net, chm

I've this situation: i've buld a .net application that use .chm file as Integrated Help, when user press F1, `Help.ShowHelp` is invoked like in this example:

```
Help.ShowHelp(ctrl, HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.TopicId, GetTopicId(ctrl));
```

This work like a charm on my machine in Application debug and release mode. But when i try to do the same on other machine (Windows XP, equal my working machine), when user press f1, nothing append, Help File is not opened.

I've done some tests. I'm sure HelpNamespace (string containing chm file path) is correct, i've tried do something more simple:

```
Help.ShowHelp(ctrl, HelpNamespace);
```

This work but is not context sensitive. I'm not able tu understend what append on the remote machine and why the seconth example work and first not.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem can be?

Comment: I am not sure, but try right click on the file, select Properties and make sure there is no problem with security.

Comment: @Anuraj thanks but files are ok, chm are readables :(

Comment: I noticed something very strange: the chm files are managed by hh.exe that is able to invoke chm using a topicid, well... on my machine hh.exe is working, on remote machine (were i'have no control) hh.exe is not working, if i try to execute hh.exe from console, nothing append, on my computer hh.exe show me a messagebox when i try to run it from console.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem. My Machine is Windows XP Service Pack 3, Remote machine is Windows XP with no SP. I ask system administrator to update machine, after i've made new install of my Application and all work fine.

Before ask Administrator to update machine (that in all cases is a good practice, i don't know why a lot sys admin don't do this!) i've do this tests:

on my machine from command line i have emulated the comand probably called from `Help.ShowHelp`:

```
hh.exe -mapid 2900 ms-its:C:\Programs\AppFolder\Help.chm
```

if all work fine this command show chm file with Selected TopicId, this command, on remote machine don't produce anything and this is the reason that convinced me to ask for an update of the system